# How to enable autostart option for my app in ASUS zenfone2 and other ASUS models

Tags: android

I tried a lot of solution and links but nothing being helpful, there were many links for MI and few more, but no particular solution there for ASUS phone, so if any body have solution that works, please provide such solution.Because I am not able to know exact activity name of ASUS phone

Comment: If any solution there to do it programmatically, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,
1.From the HOME screen, tap on APPS.
2. From the APPS screen, tap on the AUTO-START MANAGER icon.
3.You will first see the DOWNLOADED apps field you can toggle apps to ALLOW or DENY with a tap in this field.
Choose the APPS accordingly to your preference to which you want to start up on first boot which also gives it full start up privilege access in RAM on the OS level.
4.Tapping on the PRELOADED option will show the PRELOADED apps. Choose with you want to toggle privileges by tapping on the applicable app to ALLOW or DENY start-up access in the OS.
5.Finally, tapping on ADVANCE options/settings (The three dots on the upper right hand corner) will toggle advance selections for the AUTO-START MANAGER app. Selections to choose are - SORT BY, SHOW ALL APPS, ENABLE NOTIFICATIONS, RESTORE TO INITIAL CONFIGURATION, NOTICE, FEEDBACK & HELP.

Did you try this ?

Comment: but I need to do it on programmatically, so is there any such solution

Comment: no man, Did u manage to handle it on other manufacturers(Xiaomi, OnePlus, Oppo, Vivo, Lenovo and Huawei) pro-grammatically? Few developers here said when they try to handle this they will end up crashing their apps in certain devices so i didn't give a try.  If you know it will be helpful to me. Thanks

Comment: ya, I tried to implement pro-grammatically in few phones like Xiaomi